# SQL Server 2000 -- Log Shipping reliability?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I've been asked to look into log shipping for SQL Server 2000 (yes, 2000): something in my memory tells me that I looked at this years ago and there were question marks over it's reliability.

I'm trying to google stuff, but given the age of 2000 now I've put pulled up anything to confirm this -- most seem to say they're using it without problem, so just want confirm whether I'm just being delusional, or whether there were problems, but with a fully patched SP4 box these don't exist any more.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent 10 years administrating SQL Server 2000, and having participated in several recoveries in that period, I can assure you that this a robust and well tested recovery mechanism.

Comment: Ta. Can't find anything against this either. My memory is being delusional obviously...